# heading angle calculation using atan2

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to find heading angle for my three wheeled robot my robot setup is as below
[image]

I know all co-ordinate values.
(x1 y1) (x2 y2) two back wheels and (x3 y3) is front wheel co-ordinate

(xm ym) is the midpoint of (x1 y1) and (x2 y2)

(xt yt) is the target point

I am trying to find angle between (x3 y3) and (xt yt)

For the first case angle range must be  0 to +180 and for second case angle range must be  0 to -180 to make necessary turnings.

How can I use atan2 method for this? Is there any other better method to find angle in the necessary range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a line from (xm,ym) to (x3,y3) and another line between (xm,ym) and (xy,yt).
Now all you interesting in is the angle between the two lines. 
The answer is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1269050/finding-the-angle-between-two-line-equations).

This is officially unanswered question, but the correct answer is there. 
Pick up the one with highest votes (Rory Daulton) and you good. Just use $\mathrm{atan2}$ instead of $\tan^{-1}$

Comment: Thanks for your reply  I took few numerical examples and plotted on a graph. Equation `180 - |atan2(v1) - atan2(v2)|` didn't work but this `atan2(v1) - atan2(v2)` works. Not sure I'm doing right or wrong

Comment: you don't need the 180-....  thing, the atan2(v1) - atan2(v2) is the only thing you need, it is signed, so always work